# Login faild for user 'SOFTWARE\Soft'

Tags: sql-server

Cannot open database "SystematicDBSearch" requested by the login.Login faild for user 'SOFTWARE\Soft'.Where is a problem.

Comment: Its not the problem,I have checked it already.

Answer (score 1):

your login doesn't have permissions on that database. or the database doesn't exist.